# Monitoring tablespace usage in Oracle XE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe, tablespace

As it says on the [Oracle XE overview page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html):

> Oracle Database XE can be installed on any size host machine with any number of CPUs (one database per machine), but XE will store **up to 4GB of user data**, use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the host machine.

Now if I want to monitor the database to see how much user data is in use or how much memory is the database using, how would I do that? It is possible to monitor these values from Oracle Application Express, but I want to monitor the database from a centralized monitoring system. [Oracle XE documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/storage.htm#CHDHGJEB) presents a query which returns Flash Recovery Area usage, so I'm guessing there's a similar query for user data usage also.

```
SELECT
NAME,
TO_CHAR(SPACE_LIMIT, '999,999,999,999') AS SPACE_LIMIT,
TO_CHAR(SPACE_LIMIT - SPACE_USED + SPACE_RECLAIMABLE,'999,999,999,999')
   AS SPACE_AVAILABLE,
ROUND((SPACE_USED - SPACE_RECLAIMABLE)/SPACE_LIMIT * 100, 1)
   AS PERCENT_FULL
FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;
```

Also, what happens when user data is above the limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shamelessly taken from the [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tablespace#Check_free.2Fused_space_per_tablespace) website, here is a query that checks used space by tablespace:

```
SELECT /* + RULE */  df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
       df.bytes / (1024 * 1024) "Size (MB)",
       SUM(fs.bytes) / (1024 * 1024) "Free (MB)",
       Nvl(Round(SUM(fs.bytes) * 100 / df.bytes),1) "% Free",
       Round((df.bytes - SUM(fs.bytes)) * 100 / df.bytes) "% Used"
  FROM dba_free_space fs,
       (SELECT tablespace_name,SUM(bytes) bytes
          FROM dba_data_files
         GROUP BY tablespace_name) df
 WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name
 GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,df.bytes
UNION ALL
SELECT /* + RULE */ df.tablespace_name tspace,
       fs.bytes / (1024 * 1024),
       SUM(df.bytes_free) / (1024 * 1024),
       Nvl(Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_used) * 100 / fs.bytes), 1),
       Round((SUM(fs.bytes) - df.bytes_free) * 100 / fs.bytes)
  FROM dba_temp_files fs,
       (SELECT tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used
          FROM v$temp_space_header
         GROUP BY tablespace_name,bytes_free,bytes_used) df
 WHERE fs.tablespace_name (+)  = df.tablespace_name
 GROUP BY df.tablespace_name,fs.bytes,df.bytes_free,df.bytes_used
 ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

By default, user data is the space used in the `USERS` tablespace.

As for what happens when you are at the limit, I can only guess that:

- You will get some *out of space* error when trying to insert data (some Oracle error message always seem to come from *out of space* anyway ;-)
- You may be in for the biggest check in your life...

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. It seems that Oracle XE gives an error saying "ORA-12952: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 4 GB." I hope 4 GB is enough. :-)

Comment: The 11g Express Edition (yet to be released) has been described as going up to 10GB.

Comment: @GaryMyers, 11g XE [allows 11GB of user data](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html).

Comment: `You may be in for the biggest check in your life...`:  If you need to store more data, and [Oracle Database](http://www.oracle.com/database) is too expensive, try [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) instead.

Answer (score 1):

A closely-related matter: tablespace usage by user (to find out where the space is going):

```
select owner,tablespace_name,
sum(bytes)/1024/1024 as mbytes
from dba_segments
group by owner,tablespace_name
order by mbytes desc;
```